# Three.js import object from blender causes weird peeling of materials

Tags: three.js

I seem to have a problem importing a json object exported from Blender.

[image: peeling object]

Everything seems to be working fine, but the materials aren't rendering correctly.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this peeling occurs?

I'm adding it simply via the *ObjectLoader*

```
function jsonLoad(url) {

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load(url, function (geometry, materials) {
        scene.add(geometry);

    });


}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: does the object have the proper UV coordinates?

Comment: @2pha Hi! Yes, they have. To contextualize, when I export it as a Collada file, it works properly. But when I export using the three.js exporter, it becomes all messed up. Thanks for the help! :(

Comment: Am guessing you are using the new Three.js exporter. Have you tried playing with the export settings? I have the same workflow COLLADA to BLENDER to THREE JS. I don't have issues. Possible for object to be privoded to test?